# How to convert a ref [enum type] to a ref int?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, pass-by-reference, interlocked

I want to use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` with an enum type that inherits from int, like so:

```
public enum MyEnum : int { A, B }

public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly MyEnum s_field = MyEnum.A;

    public void Foo()
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref s_field, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.A) == MyEnum.A)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Changed from A to B");
        }
    }
}
```

However, `CompareExchange` only works with reference types and select value types (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange(v=vs.110).aspx)). Since a `MyEnum` is really an int underneath the skin, I thought I should be able to pass it as a ref int:

```
// should call CompareExchange(ref int, int, int) overload
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref s_field, (int)MyEnum.B, (int)MyEnum.A);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work either. I get the following error:

> Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref MyEnum' to 'ref int'

Casting before passing it in, e.g. `ref (int)s_field`, doesn't help either.

How can I fix this? Is there any way to use `CompareExchange` with enums, or must I use ints instead?

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you work with enums? `Interlocked` is limited to numbers in this regareds ... can you work with constants (I know, ... design smell, though)?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Yep, I just think the code looks nicer with enums.

Comment: You can't do what you want since `Interlocked` doesn't provide an `enum` variant of the API. You have to use an `int`.

Comment: why dont you first convert it into int and then pass the variable to ref ?

Comment: Your field is `readonly` and you want to pass it ByRef from a method (i.e. not a constructor)? Why should that be allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is now possible with the `Unsafe` class which was introduced in .NET Core. Run this to install the package containing the class into your app:

```
Install-Package System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe
```

In .NET 5+ this is built-in already.

Then you can do:

```cs
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref Unsafe.As<MyEnum, int>(ref s_field), (int)MyEnum.B, (int)MyEnum.A)
```

Note that this requires C# 7 language support for ref returns, so you need to have VS2017 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Would you want to use union?

```
public enum MyEnum : int { A, B }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct IntEnumUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public MyEnum Enum;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Int;
}

private static IntEnumUnion s_field;
```

```
s_field.Enum = MyEnum.A;

if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref s_field.Int, (int)MyEnum.B, (int)MyEnum.A)
    == (int)MyEnum.A)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Changed from A to B");
}
```

Of course, it is little cumbersome...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just use:

```
static readonly object lockInstance = new object();

public static TSimple CompareExchange<TSimple>(ref TSimple location1, TSimple value, TSimple comparand)
{
  lock (lockInstance)
  {
    var location1Read = location1;
    if (EqualityComparer<TSimple>.Default.Equals(location1Read, comparand))
    {
      // location1 write
      location1 = value;
    }
    return location1Read;
  }
}
```

Caution: The `lock` thing only prevents changes to `location1` occurring *through this particular method*. It cannot prevent other threads from manipulating `location1` by other means while my method runs. If this is a problem, maybe use `int` and have `public static class MyEnum { public const int A = 0; public const int B = 1; }`.

Answer (score -1):

What about converting the value after the evaluation?

```
        int value = (int)MyEnum.A;

        var result = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, (int)MyEnum.A, (int)MyEnum.B);

        if((MyEnum)result == MyEnum.A)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Changed from A to B");
```